# Why a deconstruction cannot mix declarations and expressions on the left

Tags: c#, tuples

I have this code:

```
public static (int a, int b) f12()
{
    return (1, 2);
}

public static void test()
{
    int a;
    (a, int b) = f12(); //here is the error
}
```

When I try to compile it I get an error:

> A deconstruction cannot mix declarations and expressions on the left

I don't understand why. Any suggestions?

Comment: I presume it is because you have a declaration in your expression: int b

Comment: Please don't ask "why" questions; they're hard to answer. "What line of the specification describes this rule?" is a question with an answer. The answer to a "why" question is "because that's what the spec says."  Why does the spec say that? Because that was what the language designers decided. Why did they decide that? You'll have to ask them.

Comment: Try `var b = f12()`.

Comment: @EricLippert I believe these _why_ questions stem from people expecting a feature in one programming language to be there in all the others.

Comment: In fairness, some "why" questions are eminently answerable. To somebody who doesn't know either answer, there isn't a clear bright line between this one and "Why can't I cast `List<SubClass>` to `List<BaseClass>`.

Comment: Yes, experts ask concise, precise and nice questions. I do the same each time I can.
Even if it was an hard question because of "why", I think it was clear and deserved an answer like Brian's one. In my humble opinion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

###### Update:

As OfirD points out, [This feature was added to C# 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/deconstruct#tuples) .

###### Original Answer:

> When I try to compile it I get an error:
>
> A deconstruction cannot mix declarations and expressions on the left I
> don't understand why.

As Eric said, the best place to get an answer to a "why" question is from the designers.  Conveniently, the meeting notes for the C# design are actually posted publicly.  So, we can actually answer such questions!

Quoting the meeting notes, the reason you cannot mix declarations and expressions:

> [Supporting mixed declarations and expressions] was a late design
> change we didn't get to implementing.

As of now, adding this feature to a future versions of C# 7.X is under consideration.

Relevant links:

- https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/meetings/2017/LDM-2017-02-21.md#mixing-fresh-and-existing-variables-in-deconstruction
- https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/125 .

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer and for the information on how to find this answer by myself.

Comment: @Brian, you may want to update your answer, as this feature is available on C# 10 ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/deconstruct#tuples)).

Answer (score 3):

This is a more precise answer to my question:

> May lead to occasional confusion, as in M((int x, y) = e) (declaring
>   y)? [...]

Taken from [Mixing fresh and existing variables in deconstruction](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/meetings/2017/LDM-2017-02-21.md#mixing-fresh-and-existing-variables-in-deconstruction) mentioned by Brian's answer.

Comment: I think the precise answer to your question is : due to the press of time, this hasn't been implemented yet, but will be sometime in the future.